# Alt-Tab when LibreOffice is open causes OS to crash

Tags: release-freya, libreoffice

I've been trying elementary OS, and is in fact the best Linux distribution.

The only problem that I can report, and I haven't seen anyone complaining about it, is that LibreOffice Word is crashing the system frequently (or just halting all processes, even <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

I'm a PHP developer using PHPStorm, and if I open LibreOffice to check some error doc, I can't do more then 2 Alt-Tabs; the first swich works fine, and the second just freases everything. 
I've done some testing, if I have PHPStorm and file manager, everything is ok; if I have LibreOffice and File Manager, the same problem, that's why I'm blaming Libre.

Does Anyone have an idea what is going on???

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards From Portugal

Comment: Thanks for the text-editions to a bi-lingual wannabe...

I managed to fix it, by change some packages-updates, not the recommended, the graphic card update options.

Best Regards