# After working a while, Freya freezes every process except mouse

Tags: release-freya, crash

Good morning community,

I already posted my first error experience on: [Alt-Tab when LibreOffice is open causes OS to crash](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3976/alt-tab-when-libreoffice-is-open-causes-os-to-crash)

I really don't get it what is happening... Working as a WebDev, with PHPStorm (but also happens with LibreOffice), and while I'm changing windows (or even when I'm just typing) Freya stops responding to everything and can't access anything.

It just freezes, mouse moves but can't click anywhere, can't access to keyboard shortcuts, can't go to shell terminal, etc. I even had music playing, and when the file ended, it didn't go to the next song.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening??? Or if there is some kind of error file that I'm not aware???

Thanks in advance and Best Regards